# MapBox Find terrain class by coordinates in Android

Tags: android, mapbox

I spent several hours looking for simple solution and still haven't found one.

MapBox style editor uses this simple feature. That you can hover and click over map, and it shows small popup stating all terrain classes you enabled in your map.

Question, how to do it in Android version of MapBox given I have installed my style. Now I want click on any place in the map and get the same popup stating, for example, that this is building, woods, background here. Or other place would satte, that this is major road.

This IS doable as MapBox studio itself shows. i can't believe it uses some API not available for anyone, as this is one API no map provider gives, while still able correctly draw terrain. What so complex to add this API?

And NO I am not interested in address. I am interested exactly on terrain, for simple task - distinguiosh water from non-water, road from non-road, building, from non-building, don't care where it is by address, so reverse geolocation does not work. Or simpler - I need SIMPLER geolocation, than address.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions kind of confusing but I'll try and help. If I'm reading correctly, you are trying to create an Android app that uses an API similar to Mapbox Studio that allows the user to select/distinguish the difference between objects on the map such as buildings, water, forest, etc.

If this is the case, then first you must understand that Mapbox Studio is using OpenStreetMap data to distinguish between objects. These objects are stored in a database with tags. It's tough to explain so i'll just leave a brief reading [wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) that might help.

To my knowledge, there isn't any API's specific to Android that will give you the kind of information you're looking for. However, if I was in your dilemma I'd take a look at the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) as it's a complex query tool that allows you to send coordinates to it and it will return all the tags (such as building or water) at that location within a JSON object. From there you can parse and use the data in your app. It is very powerful so I suggest reading up on how to use it and test using a website called [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu), that's if you decide to use it.

Nevertheless, I hope this helps and I understood your question correctly.